# Scala trait composition issue

Tags: scala, traits

I have a class which source I cannot modify:

```
class Foo {

  def bar() = println("bar")

}
```

And a trait I'd like to mix into it at runtime

```
trait Zee { this: Foo =>

  abstract override def bar() = {
    println("before bar")
    super.bar()
  }
}
```

This is throwing that `bar is not a member of Object with ScalaObject`

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to achieve this without modifying `Foo` source?

The ultimate client code needs to look like this:

```
val foo = new Foo with Zee
foo.bar() // should print 'before bar' and then 'bar'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Zee trait has no super traits (except implicit inheritance from ScalaObject) thus super does not contain definition for `bar` and there is nothing to override or call (super.bar).

why don't you write this without self-reference?

```
class Foo {

  def bar() = println("bar")

}


trait Zee extends Foo {

  abstract override def bar() = {
    println("before bar")
    super.bar()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just extends the class Foo in your trait:

```
trait Zee extends Foo
```

And your code will work.

Answer (score 2):

your trait needs to `extend` foo

```
trait Zee extends Foo {
  abstract override def bar() = {
    println("before bar")
    super.bar()
  }
}
```